# UDK and Mercurial - hgignore regex

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore, unreal-development-kit

I'm looking at using Mercurial for version control in a project, and was hoping you stackers could help me out with the regex, so that the .hgignore isn't a disgusting GLOB-by mess.

The big ignore directories are easy, however keeping certain sub-folders tracked has me stumped.

Here's the list of what I (believe) need **INCLUDED** for coding purposes.

```
Development/Src/OurGame
Development/Src/<all files in this directory, but not subfolders>
UDKGame/Config/DefaultGame.ini
UDKGame/Config/DefaultEngine.ini
```

If only there was the option for a .hginclude rather than .hgignore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ignore everything and then use `hg add` to add the specific files that you want.  The `.hgignore` file is only used to ignore things that haven't already been added to the repository.

Other than that, you do need to specify the files to ignore so I don't think that people could help you with this question without know what the files are that you don't want to track.

Comment: Can I add folders though, or only specific files?

Comment: Only files.  Mercurial doesn't track folders.